# Vue remove child component with it state

Tags: vue.js, components

I want delete child component. I use this.rows.splice(index, 1)

When i call this.rows.splice(index, 1) VueJs always remove last component from this.$children and save internal state in component.$data ;

Example is here

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/abratko/gc7h1r34/3/`
```

How fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Vue associates each data item with each vnode according to the item's index by default. This results in existing Vue components being reused, but bound to different items, when re-rendering the list after an item was removed from the array.

This is why you should always bind `key` to a value which uniquely identifies that particular item. In your example, since each item is a unique string you can just bind to that:

```vue
<row-component v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row">
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```